# Ruby on Rails Calculating md5 of image with command line ``

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, rubygems, md5

I am trying to generate a md5 hash of images in both a ruby script and on a ruby on rails server.

In the script (which is run locally on a mac) I am doing:

```
`md5 -q path-to-file`
```

Which works perfectly fine and generates something like `Added new md5: efe99a09e6e1b192314891b960018bd4` When I run the same command on the server (running in production on a linux machine), it comes up as an empty string

```
def add_md5_if_empty(test_image)
  if md5.nil?
    self.md5 = `md5 -q #{test_image.image.path}`
    logger.info "Added new md5: #{self.md5} for image at path: #{test_image.image.path}"
    test_image.save
  end
end


I, [2016-02-24T03:48:36.879648 #42]  INFO -- : Added new md5:  for image at path: /app/public/system/test_images/images/000/209/309/original/filename.png
```

My guess is that the ruby on rails server (linux machine) doesn't have the md5 command. Also my project is using Docker so maybe there is some dependency I am missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure Ruby:

```
require 'digest/md5'
# ...
self.md5 = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(File.binread(test_image.image.path))
```

EDIT: Simpler:

```
self.md5 = Digest::MD5.file(test_image.image.path).hexdigest
```